# Why does CreateRemoteThread() cause a Debug Assertion Failed error?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, dll, code-injection

I stumbled upon [a tutorial about dll injection in c](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/using-createremotethread-for-dll-injection-on-windows/). When I run my code, it gives me a Debug Assertion Failed error when I use the `CreateRemoteThread()` function in my code.

I use Visual Studio Express 2015 on Windows 10

The Error:

[image: Error I get]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
char* buffer = "C:\\inject2.dll";

//Get the process handle passing in the process ID
int procID = 9872;
HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);

if (process == NULL) {
    printf("Error: the specified process couldn't be found\n");
}


//Get the address of the LoadLibrary function
LPVOID addr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

if (addr == NULL) {
    printf("Error: the LoadLibraryA function was not found inside kernel32.dll library.\n");
}



//Allocate new memory region inside the process's address space
LPVOID arg = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(process, NULL, strlen(buffer), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

if (arg == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: the memory could not be allocated inside the chosen process.\n");
}



//Write the argument to LoadLibraryA to the process's newly allocated memory region
int n = WriteProcessMemory(process, arg, buffer, strlen(buffer), NULL);

if (n == 0) {
    printf("Error: there were not bytes written to the process's address space.\n");
}




//Inject our DLL into the process's address space
HANDLE threadID = CreateRemoteThread(process, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)addr, arg, NULL, NULL);

if (threadID == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: the remote thread could not be created.\n");
}

else
{
    printf("Success: the remote thread was succesfully created.\n");
}


//Close the handle to the process because we have already injected the DLL

CloseHandle(process);
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CreateRemoteThread` is part of the Windows API. The Windows API doesn't issue debug assertions. Don't let us guess, provide the information, where your code fails. A debugger is a great tool to evaluate a callstack, at the time when code fails. Use it.

Comment: Is the crash occurring in the process that is calling CreateRemoteThread, or in the process that is being injected into?  If the latter, you need to post the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the DLL from the link you supplied, it's probably failing because it's attempting to write to the root of the system drive (`"C:\\temp.txt",`). Change this path to something your target process can write to.